# Linking Bugzilla to a specific project in Teamcity

Tags: teamcity, bugzilla

I have teamCity having multiple projects and multiple Issue tackers (Bugzila (4 connections) +  redmmine). Problem am facing is for every project, if I use number in my SVN comments, it gets linked to Redmine. I want to link particular issue tracker with particular project . How can I do this association ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Teamcity this is not yet supported as of today (28th Nov,2012). I have found an alternate .What you can do is create multiple instance of bug-tracker like Bugzilla or Redmine. Use regex for tracking bug number,but the pattern should be unique. And ez to remember is to add your project name as prefix with bug number , and it will work .